# How to decrypt a file using privateKey.pem created with openssl in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, openssl, commoncrypto

I am trying to decrypt a file which was encrypted using the openssl smime command.

Here are the steps I am following to create the certificate and encrypt the file.

For encryption: openssl smime -encrypt -binary -aes-256-cbc -in testFile.zip -out testFile.zip.enc -outform DER testCert.pem

I have created a certificate using this command-

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myPrivateKey.pem -out testCert.pem -days 365

Now, this file has been encrypted and saved to a server. I am downloading this file in my iOS Application.

Once Downloaded, I need to decrypt the file. Now, I am unable to do the same using Swift. 
Is there a library or sample code that could help me get started in decrypting the file ?
I am very new to iOS and Cryptography.

I did have a look at the CommonCrypto and CryptoSwift. But haven't really got the solution yet.

I expect to get the zip file decrypted and stored at Directory or Library folder inside the application.